# Array Reduce giving undefined results for data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, highcharts, axios

I am trying to accumulate JSON values based on unique values of the name. But I keep getting data as undefined.

My JSON:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2019-09-16",
        "browser": "Firefox",
        "hello": 487586,
        "bye": 398217
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-09-16",
        "browser": "Firefox",
        "hello": 2661089,
        "bye": 2111027
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-09-16",
        "browser": "Chrome",
        "hello": 218492,
        "bye": 164685
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-09-16",
        "browser": "IE",
        "hello": 164572,
        "bye": 86309
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-09-16",
        "browser": "Chrome",
        "hello": 67534,
        "bye": 19736
    }
]
```

My Code:

```
let json = `json_url`;
let Social_Media = ['Facebook', 'Instagram', 'Twitter', 'LinkedIn', 'TikTok'];

axios.get(json, {
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
          api_requests.json_count = c;
        })
      })
      .then(function(json_counts) {
        let json_chart_data = json_counts.data;

        let val = [...new Set(json_chart_data.map(({
          nm
        }) => nm))];
        console.log(val);

        series = val.reduce((a, c, i) => {
          console.log(a);
          cur_data = json_chart_data.filter(d => {
            return d.nm === c
          }).sort(compare_values('date'));

          return [...a, {
            name: c.replace(/_/g, ' '),
            data: cur_data.reduce((aa, cc) => {
              // console.log(aa);
              return [...aa, {
                x: +date(cc),
                y: +cc.hello,
                bye: +cc.bye
              }];
            }, []),
            Social: Social_Media[i]
          }];
        }, []);
```

`val` returns `["Firefox","Chrome","IE"]`

I expect `console.log(a)` to return:

```
[]
[0:{data:[json_data for Firefox]}, name:"Firefox", Social_Media:"Facebook"}]
[0:{data:[json_data for Firefox]}, name:"Firefox", Social_Media:"Facebook"}, 1:{data:[json_data for Chrome]}, name:"Chrome", Social_Media:"Instagram"}]
...
```

I am getting:

```
[]
[0:{data:undefined}, name:"Firefox", Social_Media:"Facebook"}]
[0:{data:undefined}, name:"Firefox", Social_Media:"Facebook"}, 1:{data:undefined}, name:"Chrome", Social_Media:"Instagram"}]
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to combine all the results for each type of browser. Is it because I am finding the unique browsers and then using the reduce method to combine them?

Comment: You never do anything inside `reduce`. Somehow you get result that suggests otherwise.

Comment: @VLAZ, I have edited my code

Comment: I have a feeling you are omitting some details here. Nothing I can see in this code would allow `data` to be assigned `undefined`. You may be doing weird things with mixing objects and arrays, though. What exactly is `a`? Is it an array or object? You're console logging `a.data`, but then spreading `a` into an Array.

Comment: @Jacob, The only thing I omitted is the building of the chart. Thats outside the reduce method. That was my bad. the console.log(a) is the result I am expecting above

Comment: `let val = [...new Set(json_chart_data.map(({nm}) => nm))];` will create an array of nm` already then in the following line `val.filter(d => {return d.nm === c` `d.nm` will be `undefined` so `cur_data` will always be an empty array.

Comment: @AZ_ , How do I fix that?

Comment: I think it supposed to be `val.filter(d => {return d=== c` or simpler `val.filter(d => d===c)`, even with this issue you data should have been `[]` not `undefined`.

Comment: I still think we're missing some things. Try to create a minimum reproduceable  snippet. For example, what is `channel`? What is `json_counts`? Of course, you'll probably find the issue once you start generating the snippet (at least I usually do)

Comment: I'd start by using meaningful, clear to follow variable names. Then add a few debuggers and you'll solve the problem easily

Comment: @Jacob, Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rprak0605/0xnmsgzc/7/ .

Comment: @chrispbacon, Ive tried the debuggers but i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: @noob: the fiddle doesn't work. I'd recommend you reduce your JS to just the part after the HTTP requests and try to reproduce purely with the data transformations. There's currently way too much guess work for us.

Comment: This was fixed by me changing the `json_count = c;` to another variable name. I dont know why and can't seem to figure out why but it worked. Thank you all for your help